# Correct way to fix number of line in Text

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile, view

Need only one line in the component Text

I tried this code `Text numberOflines={1} ellipsizeMode='tail' style={{color: 'red'}}`

Not working, still getting two.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo. it's `numberOfLines` not `numberOflines`

Comment: Thanx, seems like the syntax check is missing feature while using VSC.